# Declare type of function in contract

Tags: function, haskell, types

so i am struggling a bit with type of functions.

I have a function

```
prop_merge_check xs ys = length (merge xs ys) == length (sort (xs ++ ys))
```

how can i assign type for each element of the function?

I tried this way

```
prop_merge_check :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

and also this way

```
prop_merge_check xs ys = length (merge (xs::[a]) (ys::[a])) == length (sort ((xs::[a]) ++ (ys::[a])))
```

But it doesn't seem to work out for me.

Need help pls

Errors are

> ```
> • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘merge’
>   prevents the constraint ‘(Ord a0)’ from being solved.
>   Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
>   These potential instances exist:
>     instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Either a b)
>       -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
>     instance Ord Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
>     instance Ord Integer
>       -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type’
>     ...plus 23 others
>     ...plus 98 instances involving out-of-scope types
>     (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
> • In the first argument of ‘length’, namely
>     ‘(merge (xs :: [a]) (ys :: [a]))’
>   In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely
>     ‘length (merge (xs :: [a]) (ys :: [a]))’
>   In the expression:
>     length (merge (xs :: [a]) (ys :: [a]))
>       == length (sort ((xs :: [a]) ++ (ys :: [a])))
> ```

And

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘merge’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Ord a0)’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Either a b)
      -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
    instance Ord Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
    instance Ord Integer
      -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type’
    ...plus 23 others
    ...plus 98 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In the first argument of ‘length’, namely
    ‘(merge (xs :: [a]) (ys :: [a]))’
  In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely
    ‘length (merge (xs :: [a]) (ys :: [a]))’
  In the expression:
    length (merge (xs :: [a]) (ys :: [a]))
      == length (sort ((xs :: [a]) ++ (ys :: [a])))
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: @DevNebulae it says couldn`t match expected type.

Comment: Please post the whole error message. Then we can check what it should be.

Comment: Looks ok to me.  Post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the error message please

Comment: test run your full code at tio.run or repl.it. your 2nd line goes above your first, then it's OK (you don't need the third line). you probably use it with incompatible argument.

Comment: @DevNebulae Ive added the errors.

Comment: thanks guys! Found answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, the type is not part of the `Eq` type class, but is part of the `Ord` type class. `Eq` specifies how to equal two things and `Ord` specifies whether something is less than (`LT`), greater than (`GT`) or equal to (`Eq`) something.

Changing your type to: `prop_merge_check :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool` should work.